# NPM script that runs command for each file in folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, npm-scripts

I currently have this pretty npm script that runs the `electron` command on each file in a folder:

```
"test": "electron . --input './test/line.svg' --output './test' --headless && electron . --input './test/script.svg' --output './test' --headless && electron . --input './test/xlink.svg' --output './test' --headless && electron . --input './test/multitransform.svg' --output './test' --headless",
```

Is it possible to rewrite this script as a loop?

I have found scripts that work on Linux, but haven't found any solution for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use a premade NPM package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-for-every-file).